# moving folder older than 30 days to another folder

Tags: ubuntu

I have a directory which has folders of everyday and every folder has 1000 of images in it. I want to archive folders older than 30 days to archeive folder.

I tried this and it bugged up everything, It copied all the image files to archeive folder instead of date folder.

```
sudo find /home/lanein1/AshtonRPOUT/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv '{}' /home/lanein1/AshtonRPOUT/Arch/ \;
```

[image]
  my script copied all the images into arch instead of folders seprately..

[image]

Comment: `f` is type "file". You probably wanted `d` - directory?

Comment: No problem, posted answer so the question can be considered answered.

Answer (score 5):

You wanted to find directory, but you are looking for plain file (`f`). Use `d` for directory search:

```
sudo find /home/lanein1/AshtonRPOUT/ -type d -mtime +30 -exec mv '{}' /home/lanein1/AshtonRPOUT/Arch/ \;
```

Comment: This may find the top directory `AshtonRPOUT`, and it may also try to enter directories that no longer exist (because they were moved).  You want `-mindepth 1` and `-prune`.

Answer (score 2):

To move all directories under `/home/lanein1/AshtonRPOUT/` that has a modification time 30 days in the past, but leave the topmost directory (`/home/lanein1/AshtonRPOUT/`) untouched, you could use

```
find /home/lanein1/AshtonRPOUT/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
    ! -path '/home/lanein1/AshtonRPOUT/Arch*' -mtime +30 \
    -exec mv {} /home/lanein1/AshtonRPOUT/Arch/ ';' -prune
```

Things to note here:

- We're looking for directories, not files, so we'll use `-type d`.
- The destination directory is included in the set of directories searched by `find`, so we use `! -path '...'` to avoid that path.
- You don't want to try to move the top directory, so we add `-mindepth 1` to start looking *beneath* that path. Likewise, `-maxdepth 1` forces `find` to not descend into the subfolders (you say you have subfolders and that these contain only files).
- (This is not necessary here, since we use `-maxdepth 1` but...) Moving a directory will change the directory structure. Therefore we add `-prune` at the end.  This removes the moved path from the list of directories that `find` will consider.  Without this, `find` would try to enter non-existent directories (if a directory was found and moved).