# Find and delete folders within directory that are older than x days

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

<sup>**Reopen voters:** The 'already answered' question, is different. I am not looking to match the folder names, I want to look at the creation date time and use this to find the x days. I will be looking for folders older than 6 months, so unless I am mistaken, the 'already answered' is incorrect.</sup>

---

Inside a directory, I store date named folders of website backups.

```
/Users/myname/Desktop/rsync/
```

As an example:

```
/Users/myname/Desktop/rsync/10-06-18
/Users/myname/Desktop/rsync/11-06-18
/Users/myname/Desktop/rsync/12-06-18
```

In my bash script, I need to check to find any direct descendants of the 'rsync' folder that are older than x days and delete them.

Using the following, I am able to find files that are older than 2 days, but this is within the child folders as well.

```
find /Users/myname/Desktop/rsync -mtime +2 -print
```

If anyone can show me how I would limit this to just the direct descendant folder and potentially how to delete them, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You first point out that you have folders with dates in their names, but you don't want to use these date?  Also, the datestamp of _creation_ is most likely not stored, unless that's what the folder name is.

Comment: I added another dupe. This looks at the modification time of folders, and at least one answer discusses `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth`, which is what you want to use, along with `-prune`.

Comment: See also a similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228216/moving-folder-older-than-30-days-to-another-folder  Note that you will want to add `-maxdepth 1` to this, apart from taking my comment to the (currently only) answer there into account.

Comment: Are the modification timestamps of those date-stamped directories not in alignment with their filename-date?